# How can I access the Text in a Label from one form while I am in a different form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem accessing the value of a `Label` from one form while in the context of a different form. I can access the default label value in the second form, but when I change the label value and try to send to another form, I get the default value of the label not the new value.

Code in form1:

```
public String text1
{            
    get { return label2.Text; }
    set { label2.Text = value; }
}
```

Code in form2

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    MessageBox.Show("" + frm.text1);
}
```

Comment: BTW: ""+frm.text1 is the same as frm.text1

Answer (score 2):

You need to hand over a reference to `Form1` when you create your second form. Something like:

```
// this is where you open Form2 from Form1
private void button_openForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this); 
    f2.Show();
}
```

Then in Form2 you have:

```
// declare this field in your Form2 class:
Form1 f1;

// this is your constructor in Form2
public Form2(Form1 f1)
{
    this.f1 = f1; // some field or property to hold Form1
    // possibly other work to do here
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + f1.text1);
}
```

Another possibility is to make `text1` static.

Comment: where should i write the Form2 f2 = new Form2(this); in form 1?
in form2 i got some error in
this.f1 = f1;

Comment: I suppose you open your `Form2` somewhere in `Form1`? Then that's where you write `Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);` In `Form2` you need to declare a field for `Form1`. I'll update my answer with examples, just a sec.

Comment: Form2 tambahData = new Form2(this);
show error when i write "this" -> form2(this);

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have the constructor in `Form2` that accepts an argument of the right type?

Comment: the constructor, i think i dont have it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write what error exactly you are getting. I'm just guessing here ;)

Comment: 'myproject.Form2' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form frm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

    //Here textbox1 is the control name which has the value in Form1
    MessageBox.Show("" + frm .Controls["textbox1"].Text);
}
```

Comment: cannot implicity convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'myproject'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user2029546 What is that myproject ?

Comment: Do you have any windows from named Form in your project ?

Comment: Looks like error is coming from some other code you have. You are doing invalid type casting or assignment, Can you paste the exact code line where the error occurs ?

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            MessageBox.Show("" + frm.teks1);
        }

Comment: Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; copy this code form my post. its not Form1 frm, it should be Form frm.